# how to retrive the values for dropdown list and checkboxes from excel and use those values in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver. I am trying to retrieve the values from excel sheet for dropdownlist and checkboxes/radio button and use those values in selenium webdriver. Can you please give some suggestions for how to retrieve those values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can anyone please respond me?

Answer (score 0):

```
//download jxl.jar and put it in your build path

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

    //******************************************************************************************
    public String setWorkbook(Workbook workbook) {
    String sFullPathNameExcelFile = getXmlConfig().getString("data.input_excel");
    // hard coded:
    // String sFullPathNameExcelFile = "C:\\user\\MyExcel.xls";

    try {
        this.workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(
            sFullPathNameExcelFile));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("******* ERROR *******\n******* ERROR *******\n******* ERROR *******");
        System.out.println(sFullPathNameExcelFile+" DOES NOT EXIST OR CANNOT BE OPENED FOR INPUT.");
        System.out.println("******* ERROR *******\n******* ERROR *******\n******* ERROR *******");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return sFullPathNameExcelFile;

    }// end method

    //*****************************************************************************
    public String setSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    String sWorksheet = getXmlConfig().getString(
        "data.worksheet");

    try{
    this.sheet = workbook.getSheet(sWorksheet);}
    catch (Exception ex) {return "ERROR";}  

    return sWorksheet;
    }

    //******************************************************************************
    public Sheet getSheet() {
    return sheet;
    }   


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Workbook workbook = null;
    pca.sWorkingExcelFile = pca.setWorkbook(workbook);

    int iCol = 27; //whatever you need
    int iRow = 34; //whatever you need

    Cell cCell = null;
    Sheet sheet = pca.getSheet();

    cCell = sheet.getCell(iCol,iRow);
    String str = cCell.getContents();

    }
```